# How to download a video file from YouTube to hard disk using C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube

How to download a video file from YouTube as .FLV or .MP4 format to hard disk using .NET?
I want to create a small YouTube downloader application which asks the user for the specefic link, when i click the download button, the download process start downloading the video as an FLV file directly from YouTube server to the hard disk.

`I'm not asking here for the detailed procedure but i want to know only how to start ? is there a YouTube c# api which handle this process.`

How to download an Flv video file from YouTube to hard disk using C# ?

Thank you !

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I get stuck on WHERE TO START ?

Answer (score 4):

I think this project is interesting

https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

Answer (score 0):

try run an embed browser and add event handler to grep URLs of all resources on webpage, then you can study the protocol used by youtube.

- changing the HTML request header to simulate an iOS device may force youtube use HTML5 player , instead of flash player ( if the above method cannot track network activities inside a flash player )

Answer (score 0):

Find an open source program that can do this, and read the portion of the source code that forms the youtube requests.

For example, [gPodder](http://gpodder.org/) is my favorite application of this type, and would be a good choice if you read python code.  But I'm sure you can find others.

Once you find out the right format for requests, you can use C#'s HTTP classes such as [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).  Finally, save the data to a file.

[Google has also provided some documentation for accessing YouTube from .NET](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet), but this is more related to the social networking aspects of the site than the video content.